# How to make a discord.py command check the user's role?

Tags: python, roles, discord.py

For example, I might want only admins to be able to use the following command:

```
if ('!hello') in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Hello friend!')
```

How do I make it so only users with the "admin" role will be able to use this command? I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

Comment: Have you considered using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)?  It makes checks like this very easy, and lets you split your various commands out of a single `on_message`

Comment: `message.author.roles` returns the roles of the author of the message. Btw you should look at the dpy command system.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the discord.py documentation for the admin permission [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions).

The method you are looking for is this:

> `ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator`

Below I have written a mock example of a command that purges the channel and is only available to the admin.

```
@client.command() #Clear (purge) messages from channel (can only be used by users with administrator permissions)
    async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            await channel.purge(limit=amount,check=None,bulk=True)
        else:
            await ctx.send("You can't use that command, you are not an administrator!")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!